# How to make the navigation menu scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the demo interface here:

https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html

If you add the css class
"**navbar-fixed-top**" to the element

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
```

you get the following element:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
```

Now if you try to scroll the main content of the page, the content will still scroll as expected.

But if you try to scroll the navigation menu it is not scrollable.

**How can you make the navigation menu scrollable like the main contents but still keep the fixed header?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**You just need to take sidebar out of navbar like below**

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-header -->

                <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                            <em>Yesterday</em>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                            <em>Yesterday</em>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                            <em>Yesterday</em>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                    <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.dropdown -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                            <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                                <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                            <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                                <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                            <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                                <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                            <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                                <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                    <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.dropdown -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                    <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.dropdown -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.dropdown -->
                </ul>
                <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->


                <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
       </nav>
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar " role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="sidebar-search">
                            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html" class="active"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="icons.html"> Icons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-third-level collapse">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position:relative to the style of the new navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0;position:relative">
```

It will return the scrolling behaviour and as far as I can see, it won't mess with the design.

Comment: Hi sorry I meant to be more clear, I also wished to keep the fixed header also

Answer (score 0):

Please make clear what you actually want......

if you want sidebar to be static, Try this

```
.sidebar {
position: fixed !important;
}
```

Let me know what you actually want.

Comment: Hi Ive modified the final question

Comment: Your question is not clear.... what do you want ... Fixed navbar... fixed sidebar... Please try to make clear.....

Answer (score 0):

You got to get this component:

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation" style="left: 0px;">
...
</div>
```

Out of the elemnt `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">...` and put into `<div id="page-wrapper">...` and apply `left: 0px;` as style (as shown in the code sample).

Because, when you apply class `navbar-fixed-top` to the element nav, it gains the `position: absolute` property which effects the left side menu so by moving it into the component where the main component is located provides the scrolling all together again. Here is the full source of that components:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-header -->

        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <em>Yesterday</em>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <em>Yesterday</em>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <em>Yesterday</em>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
        </ul>
        <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->


        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>

    <div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation" style="
left: 0px;
">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse" style="
position: relative;
">
                <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">
                    <li class="sidebar-search">
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html" class="active"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw">    </i> Tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"> </i> Forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="icons.html"> Icons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-third-level collapse">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
//...
```